# Which one is yours?

Tags: questions

I went to pick up my son from playschool.

There were lots of shoes on the shoe rack.

I asked my son,

**"Which one is yours?"**

**"Which shoes are yours?"**

Can one used for shoes since there are two items.

Comment: No, but you can say "Which one**s** are yours"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the subject *shoes* is plural, you should use *ones* as such.

> **Which ones are yours?**

If you were asking about a particular singular shoe or item, then

> **Which one is yours?**

would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume shoes come in pairs, and can use:

> Which pair of shoes is yours?

or simply:

> Which pair is yours?

where it is assumed you are talking about shoes.

Pair is defined as (Google):

> a set of two things used together or regarded as a unit

and hence takes the singular form of the verb.